# How to return a column value basted on last activity date VIA MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to return the value of a column called "completed_by" where the completed_on is the max

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE activity(
id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
completed_on datetime,
completed_by int(11),
activity_code int(11)
)
```

If i have

```
100, '2013-07-01 00:00:00', 11, 20
150, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 12, 20
```

I want to return the value 11. Note the only giving value here is activity_code.

The logic should return the completed_by for the last time where activity_code = 20 was completed. I should only return 1 line

This is what I have done but not sure if this is a good query since the table activities has many records.

```
SELECT 
completed_by, 
MAX(completed_on ) AS completed_on 
FROM activity
WHERE activity_code = 5 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It's not clear what is impact of activity_code here. There is no 5 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max for one record:

```
SELECT * FROM activity 
WHERE activity_code = 20 
ORDER BY completed_on DESC LIMIT 1
```

Max for all activity codes:

```
SELECT * FROM activity a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID 
                 FROM activity b 
                 WHERE a.activity_code = b.activity_code 
                   AND b.completed_on > a.completed_on)
```

[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c450/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `order by`, without the `max()`:

```
SELECT completed_on, completed_by, completed_on AS completed_on 
FROM activity
WHERE activity_code = 5
ORDER BY completed_on desc
LIMIT 1;
```